# Feature request for Rich text editor: adding a graphic after name of Allah or Prophet (s)

Tags: feature-request, arabic

I know that some of the other SE have some custom markdown formatting allowed.  I am suggesting that if we do this for example:

> Prophet Muhammad [:s]

It should be converted to:

> Prophet Muhammad [image: peace be upon him]

Except prettier with the correct size.  We can also have similar images for the name of Allah (swt), and Sahaba and so on.  Also, if we decide the image will have Arabic text, we can have alt-text that gives the translation ("peace be upon him").

How about it?

Comment: I like the idea, but that seems to colorful. :-)

Comment: Right, that's just an example.  We can decide on the actual icon later

Comment: There are some really nice graphics suggested [here](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/554/123). Maybe turn it into a wiki post and add more?

Answer (score 10):

We should be able to use the common abbreviations directly in the markup; that way everyone would only need to know the syntax, but wouldn't have to worry about learning the markup commands themselves.  For example:

- [:saws] = صلى الله عليه وسلم
- [:as] = عليه السلام
- [:ra] = رضي الله عنه
- [:swt] = سبحانه و تعالى
- [:pbuh] (probably synonym of :saws, maybe :as)
- [:azwjl] = عز وجل
- [:rha] = رحمه الله

Comment: Why the Ruby-like notation?

Comment: @ashes999 the notation choice was arbitrary; i was just expanding on what was used in OP.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is not the optimal solution but it works just fine.

I have created a really quick userscript that provides this functionality, the notation is based on [goldPseudo](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22/goldpseudo)'s [answer](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/76/4456). When you hover over an image you will get a translation of what it means.

Here is a list of the abbreviations used:

- [:ra]   ->   [image: ra]
- [:raf]   ->   [image: raf]
- [:rap]   ->   [image: rap]
- [:as]   ->   [image: as]
- [:asf]   ->   [image: asf]
- [:asp]   ->   [image: asp]
- [:rha]   ->   [image: rhaf]
- [:saws] (or: pbuh)   ->   [image: saws]
- [:swt] (or: swta)   ->   [image: swt]
- [:azwjl]   ->   [image: azwjl]

Here adding "f" indicates feminism and "p" pluralism.

[<kbd>Download</kbd>](https://github.com/user689/Scripts/raw/master/islamic-honorifics/user-script.js)|[<kbd>Installation instructions</kbd>](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info)