# Shouldn't there be predefined arabic phrases for this site?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Feature request for Rich text editor: adding a graphic after name of Allah or Prophet (s)](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75/feature-request-for-rich-text-editor-adding-a-graphic-after-name-of-allah-or-pr)

Almost all questions/answers posted by muslim users of our site use phrases like pbuh, ra, etc. that correspond to:

- صلى الله عليه و سلم
- رضي الله تعالى عنه
- رحمۃ اللہ تعالی

Isn't it good if we use predefined [fonts](http://www.dafont.com/aga-islamic-phrases.font) or images like the ones below(Not all of them but some important ones):

[image]

It would surely impart a professional look to the site.

Comment: see also: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/75/feature-request-for-rich-text-editor-adding-a-graphic-after-name-of-allah-or-pr?rq=1

Comment: @goldPseudo: So, Is this feature approved by SE and is it on the way?

Comment: not approved yet (there would be a [[tag:status-completed]] tag if it were), i'm just pointing out that it has been brought up before.

Comment: @goldPseudo: Then, should I leave this question intact as a fresh appeal or should I delete it?

Comment: Leave it be, I'll just close it as a duplicate.